# winsock2.h, no such file or directory while installing node package

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-2013, npm, winsock

While installing node module, I am getting `winsock2.h, no such file or directory` error. Please see below text for more information.

```
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(355,5): warning MSB8003: Could not find WindowsS
an invalid version number. [c:\Playground\ng-tpl\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\mongodb-core\node_modules
  kerberos.cc
c:\users\Jay\.node-gyp\0.10.26\deps\uv\include\uv-private/uv-win.h(32): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'winsock
es\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\mongodb-core\node_modules\kerberos\build\kerberos.vcxproj]
  worker.cc
  security_credentials.cc
  security_buffer.cc
  security_buffer_descriptor.cc
c:\users\Jay\.node-gyp\0.10.26\deps\uv\include\uv-private/uv-win.h(32): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'winsock
und\ng-tpl\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\mongodb-core\node_modules\kerberos\build\kerberos.vcxproj]
c:\users\Jay\.node-gyp\0.10.26\deps\uv\include\uv-private/uv-win.h(32): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'winsock
\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\mongodb-core\node_modules\kerberos\build\kerberos.vcxproj]
c:\users\Jay\.node-gyp\0.10.26\deps\uv\include\uv-private/uv-win.h(32): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'winsock
g-tpl\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\mongodb-core\node_modules\kerberos\build\kerberos.vcxproj]
  security_context.cc
c:\users\Jay\.node-gyp\0.10.26\deps\uv\include\uv-private/uv-win.h(32): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'winsock
layground\ng-tpl\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\mongodb-core\node_modules\kerberos\build\kerberos.vcxproj
c:\users\Jay\.node-gyp\0.10.26\deps\uv\include\uv-private/uv-win.h(32): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'winsock
ng-tpl\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\mongodb-core\node_modules\kerberos\build\kerberos.vcxproj]
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/tar/-/tar-2.1.1.tgz
npm http 503 https://registry.npmjs.org/tar/-/tar-2.1.1.tgz
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/tar/-/tar-2.1.1.tgz
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/tar/-/tar-2.1.1.tgz
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/tar/-/tar-2.1.1.tgz
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing bson-ext@0.1.7
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing bson-ext@0.1.7
```

I googled around and found this is a very common issue. Most users were able to fix this issue by installing `windows 7 SDK`. I tried downlaoding & installing `windows 7 SDK`  on my machine and it failed. I assume its becuase I already have `visual studio 2013` installed on my mahcine.

Please help

Comment: You shoud post your log as text instead of troncated image in order to help us help you.